# Unrecognized selector while removing all user posts from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I tried to delete all posts that belongs to specific user, however it crashes telling me error:

> '-[FIRDataSnapshot removeValue]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x174238c20'

but if I try to `po` the child, it prints out the child.

That is how I am doing it in **Swift3**:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").queryEqual(toValue: self.currentUser.generalDetails.userName).ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                (child as AnyObject).removeValue() //This line gives the error.   
            }
        })
```

That is the child that shold be removed if `"username":"currentUser.generalDetails.userName"`:

```
posts
    -KUaMd3YgJlQvv_P-kdK//This has to be deletod with all its children
       content: 
       likes: 
       postId: 
       postImageStringUrl: close
       profileImageUrl: 
       timestamp: 
       username:
```

Wha should cause the crash?

**Edit:** I updated code like this which says that I have to :

> Consider adding ".indexOn": "posts/username" at / to your security
>   rules for better performance

however I have pretty ok security rules:

```
{ 
"rules": { 
".read": "auth != null", 
".write": "auth != null", 
"Snuses": { 
".indexOn": ["Brand", "posts/username"]
} 
} 
}
FIRDatabase.database().reference().queryOrdered(byChild: "posts/username").queryEqual(toValue: currentUser.generalDetails.userName)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
                    print("not found")
                } else {
                    for child in (snapshot.children) {
                        let element = child as! FIRDataSnapshot //the node data
                        let key = element.key //the key for the node
                        let nodeToRemove = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(key)
                        nodeToRemove.removeValue()
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: You're looking for `(child as! FIRDataSnapshot).ref.removeValue()`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please make that an answer.

Comment: This Frank acutally removes the whole posts node.

Comment: I just tested the code again and really, my snippet remove the child nodes. `ref!.queryOrdered(byChild: "text").queryEqual(toValue: "Logged in as @puf").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).ref.removeValue()
            }
        })
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are going to want to remove child by it's parent key, not the child.

Frank provided a short comment (which is actually THE answer) but here's a verbose example (Firebase 2.x but you'll get the idea):

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "posts/username").queryEqual(toValue: "someUsername")
     .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

     if ( snapshot?.value is NSNull ) {
           print("not found")
     } else {
           for child in (snapshot?.children)! {
                let element = child as! FDataSnapshot //the node data
                let key = element.key! //the key for the node
                let nodeToRemove = ref.child(byAppendingPath: key)
                nodeToRemove?.removeValue()
     }
  }
})
```

something to look for is to make sure your paths are correct.

In the above code, 'key' is the parent node name like

```
-KUaMd3YgJlQvv_P-kdK
```

If you were to use

```
let ref = element.ref
```

it would be the specific path to that node, including the node name but no other data, like this

```
root_node/posts/-KUaMd3YgJlQvv_P-kdK
```

so the idea is once you have that reference, use use the reference to remove the node.

So if ref = root_node/posts/-KUaMd3YgJlQvv_P-kdK

then ref.remove(), it will remove that reference and the child data.

Comment: I did not understand you. Can you check, I edited my question. I gotta delete the whole "-KUaMd3YgJlQvv_P-kdK" if username == some value. I do it like this because I can't define the post autogenerated key.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp See my updated verbose answer to point you in the right direction. Frank provided THE answer however.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp can you add your updated code to your question? I would suggest leaving the original code for reference and then just add on your new code. What I posted does work (just tested it) but it maybe a swift 2/3 or Firebaes 2/3 thing.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp here's a problem.  let nodeToRemove = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(key), when it's actually .reference.child("posts").child("key")

Comment: Ohh.. but it still says that "Consider adding ".indexOn": "posts/username" at / to your security rules for better performance" And not deleting :(

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp Ignore the message about indexing for now. Indexing just speeds things up and you can address it later. I updated my answer with some additional data. I believe the issue is that your paths are not correct so therefore nothing deletes. I would suggest adding a print(nodeToRemove) statement in right after let nodeToRemove = statement to see the path it thinks it's trying to remove. That will be very revealing.

Comment: Finally.. Dude thank you soooooo much for this.. I owe you a lot. I now gotta see those security rules. At least it maybe help someone new too..

Answer (score 1):

Although @Jay's answer does your job, but i was half way through already writing your answer, Give it a shot and let me know:-

```
   let refe = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")
    refe.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: currentUser.generalDetails.userName).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

       if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict {

                print(each.key)

                refe.child(each.key).removeValue(completionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                    print(ref)

                })
            }
          }
        }, withCancel: {(errO) in

    })
```

It should delete every posts that the user made.. :)

Comment: Yep, it is working also.. And I do not know why, but it is somehow easier for me to understand like this :D